# Factorize product of a power series and polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a product of an infinite power series ($e^x$ power series) with a polynomial, and I want to multiply each other to obtain the coefficients in a single infinite power series, i.e. I want to obtain the numbers $c_k$ that satisfy:

$$
\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n!} \right) \left( \sum_{m=0}^{a} a_m x^m \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k
$$

Supposing that the $a_m$ is infinite with $a_m = 0$ if $m > k$, and using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) I get:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} \frac{x^n}{n!} a_{n-m}x^{n-m} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{n-k} \frac{1}{n!} a_{n-m}x^{2n-m}
$$

but I don't know if I can go any further. Is there any way to factorize this expression? Do I need an analytic expression for the sum $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n-k} \frac{1}{n!} a_{n-m}x^{2n-m}$ ?

Comment: $\sum_{n \ge 0} b_n x^n \sum_{m = 0}^M a_m x^m = \sum_{l \ge 0} x^l \sum_{m=0}^M a_m b_{l-m}$

Comment: You have a finite series times an infinite why not just multiply out i.e  $c_0=a_0,c_1=a_1+a_0,c_2=a_2/2!+a_1+a_0, \cdots, c_a=\sum_{n=0}^a a_n/n!, c_{a+k} =\sum_{n=k} ^{a+k}a_n/n!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$  to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a  series.

> We obtain with $k\geq 0$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{c_k}&=[x^k]\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n!} \right) \left( \sum_{m=0}^{a} a_m x^m \right) \\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{1}{n!}[x^{n-k}]\sum_{m=0}^a a_mx^m\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{1}{(k-n)!}[x^k]\sum_{m=0}^a a_mx^m\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^k\frac{1}{(k-n)!}a_k[[a> k]]}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$. We also set the upper limit of the outer sum to $k$ since indices greater than $k$ do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^k$.
- In (2) we change the order of summation of the outer sum $n\to k-n$ for easier selection of the coefficient in the next step.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^k$. We also use the *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* to indicate that $c_k=0$ if $a>k$.

Comment: Thanks! I started to search about the "coefficient of" operator and that put me on the right track

Comment: @user2540549: You're welcome.